# Typescript file of nothing but exports from other files - possible or not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to convert a bunch of Javascript files in a project to use Typescript and I've come across an interesting case. There is a file which is used as a shortcut to a while bunch of functions we use across a number of different third party modules, like so:

```
export { usefulFunction1 } from 'handyThirdPartyModule1'
export { usefulFunction2 } from 'handyThirdPartyModule2'
export { usefulFunction3 } from 'handyThirdPartyModule3'
```

However, this results in a Typescript file that is essentially just definitions and as such, ts-loader refuses to build it. Is there a way this file can be set up to work the same way, but such that Typescript can actually compile it into something?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, and never had trouble doing something like this in the past. Could you maybe link to a repo with a minimal reproduction?

Comment: I’ll get the exact error in the morning but it essentially says that it doesn’t have anything to export.

Comment: Looks like handyThirdPartyModule1 are not valid modules...

Comment: If there's an error message, that should be the very first thing to share. From the wording I didn't even realize there was an error message, heh